# UIBarButtonItemに自作のアイコンを使いたい

Tags: swift, ios, objective-c, xcode

UITabBarButtonItemに自作の画像を入れたいのですがpngの画像を設定すると
32*32の画像なら大きさはちょうどいいのですが画質が荒くなってしまいます
しかし64*64の画像を設定すると大きすぎて使えません
調べてみると同じような記事がありPDFを設定するとできるそうなので
(リンクは貼れませんでした)
IllustratorでPDFを書き出し,設定してみたのですが
[image: PDFを設定した時]
このように大きくなってしまいます
どのように画像を設定すればUITabBarButtonItemに綺麗なアイコンを表示させることができるでしょうか?

Answer (score 1):

Illustratorで新規書類を作るとき、キャンバスサイズを32×32ピクセルにしておけばいいのではないでしょうか。現在の**check.pdf**のイメージサイズが128×128ピクセルになっているのは、お気付きですね？

Comment: illustratorでキャンバスサイズを変更することでできました!
ひたすらコードで小さくすることを調べていたのにもっと単純に出来たのですね......
教えていただきありがとうございます.....